# Understanding byte objects in python

Tags: python, binary, byte, entropy

Dear All: I'm trying to measure the Shannon's entropy in a compression process. For this I first generate an array of 0 and 1 which I call binary sequence `seq`, and then compress it using `zlib.compress(seq)`. For example:

```py
seq = np.array([0,0,1])
seq_compress = zlib.compress(seq)

seq_compress
[out] >>> b'x\x9cc`\x80\x00F$\x1a\x00\x00$\x00\x03'
```

This last object `set_compress` is byte type. To measure the entropy rate I need to calculate the probability of appeareance of 0 and 1 in this compressed sequence, so I need to convert `seq_compress` in a list, array or string with just 0s and 1s.

I've tried the following:

```py
import sys
bin(int.from_bytes(seq_compress, byteorder=sys.byteorder))

[out]>>>'0b1000000000000100000000000000000000000001100010000001000110000000001000000001100000011000111001110001111000'
```

Which is way longer than I expected. I understand that this has something to do with the 'bytes' object, because if I convert my initial array into byte, I get a similar effect:

```py
seq_bytes = seq.tobytes()
bin(int.from_bytes(seq_bytes, byteorder=sys.byteorder))

[out]>>>
'0b10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

I thing that this is not a big deal since the entropy of the last object is the same as in the array I started with, but I would like to know why all those 0s are added.